# Prove equivalence between sums of complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, proof-explanation

Let $z_1, z_2, ..., z_n$ be complex numbers with the same, positive modulus. Prove that: 
$$\Re\left( \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left( \frac{z_i}{z_j} \right)\right) = 0 \equiv \sum_{i=1}^nz_i = 0$$

We can rewrite $\Re\left( \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left( \frac{z_i}{z_j} \right)\right) = 0$ as $\Re\left( \left(\sum_{i=1}^n z_i \right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1{z_j} \right)\right)$, therefore when $\sum_{i=1}^nz_i = 0$, we have $\Re\left( 0 \times\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1{z_j} \right)\right) = \Re\left( 0 \right)$ = 0. But how prove converse of this implication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the common modulus  be $r >0$. Then $\frac{1}{z_j} = \frac{\overline{z_j}}{r^2}$ and  therefore
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left( \frac{z_i}{z_j} \right)
= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n z_i \right)
\left( \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{z_j} \right) \\
= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n z_i \right)
\left( \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\overline{z_j}}{r^2} \right)  
= \frac{1}{r^2} \left| \sum_{i=1}^n z_i \right|^2 \, \in\Bbb  R .
$$
It follows that the expression on the  left-hand side is a real number, and
$$
\Re\left( \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left( \frac{z_i}{z_j} \right)\right) 
= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left( \frac{z_i}{z_j} \right) = \frac{1}{r^2}  \left| \sum_{i=1}^n z_i \right|^2
$$
which is zero exactly if $\sum_{i=1}^n z_i = 0$.

Comment: 1.Why $\Re\left( \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left( \frac{z_i}{z_j} \right)\right) 
= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left( \frac{z_i}{z_j} \right)$? Isn't that true if and only if $\left( \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left( \frac{z_i}{z_j} \right)\right)$ is a real number?

Comment: @PawełIwaszkiewicz: It is a real number, because the first calculation shows that it  is  equal to $\frac{1}{r^2} \left| \sum_{i=1}^n z_i \right|^2 $,  which is a real number.